# Bash - one-liner echo with delimiter

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, delimiter, csv

So my sample code so far looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

mysampletxt="=======\nTest\n-------;----------\nDone Test\n=========="
```

I want to be able to echo it out to make it look like the following:

```
=======
Test
-------
Some code goes here
More code
----------
Done Test
==========
```

But the problem is that when I tried using AWK, sed, or IFS they also use `\n` as delimiters which I don't want that to happen as the text gets all messed up. Is there anyway I can include `;` as the delimiter and ignore `\n`?

I was looking at [this](https://superuser.com/questions/98825/how-to-check-if-a-directory-exists-in-linux-command-line). But unfortunately none of those solutions worked for me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: For more clarification: I'm trying to do is split `mysampletxt` into two from the `;` character.. And be able to insert the first part of the split text one place and the second into another.

Comment: What happens when you replace double quotes with single quotes, and just echo $mysampletxt?

Comment: Btw, replace `!#/bin/bash` by `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: What exactly do you want the `;` to do? It looks like you have two separate pieces of text to surround a third piece, but stored in a single variable.

Comment: The ; is the separator between those texts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
echo -e "${mysampletxt%;*}\nSome code goes here\nMore code\n${mysampletxt#*;}"
```

or

```
printf "%b" "${mysampletxt%;*}\nSome code goes here\nMore code\n${mysampletxt#*;}"
```

Comment: Better than my answer, I think. I'll leave it up just in case it's useful to anyone.

Comment: The `printf '%b'` approach is the better of the two -- more portable; POSIX echo isn't required to support `-e`, but `printf %b` is part of POSIX since 2008: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html

Comment: Not what I'm looking for, I know about those, but what I'm trying to do is split `mysampletxt` into two from the `;` character.. And be able to insert the first part of the split text one place and the second into another..

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to define your string with `$'...'`:

```
$ mysampletxt=$'=======\nTest\n-------;\n----------\nDone Test\n=========='
$ echo "$mysampletxt"
=======
Test
-------;
----------
Done Test
==========
```

To do the substitution also:

```
$ echo "${mysampletxt/;/$'\nSome code goes here\nMore code'}"
=======
Test
-------
Some code goes here
More code
----------
Done Test
==========
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use something other than awk or sed (maybe overkill):

```
[ap@localhost ~]$ perl -e 'print "===\n\n---\n\n;"'
===

---

;[ap@localhost ~]$python -c "print ' ====\n====\n;'"
 ====
====
;
```